# Showing left battery percentage on command line on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, battery

There is a way to show current battery information? Such as percentage?

I tried below code as with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But not working.

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0u
```

### Edit

Below is the output of the command.

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              1970年01月01日 09時00分00秒 (1534744242 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    battery-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

Comment: Please append the output of the command to your question.

Comment: OK. I edited right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acpi` will show various battery status information, e.g.,

```
$ acpi -b
Battery 0: Charging, 86%, 00:25:30 until charged
```